# How to loop through the values of an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have XML data parched in a NSMutableArray and i need to loop through the array to see all values stored in it. This may be a stupid question but this is all new to me.

The xml file looks like this

```
<list>
<item id="1">
<title>Title 1</title>
<title>Content 1</title>
</item>
<item id="2">
<title>Title 2</title>
<title>Content 2</title>
</item>
</list>
```

This is the array that all data is collected

```
NSMutableArray *articleList=[[ArticleService getArticleList] retain];
```

If i output NSLog(@"articleList: %@", articleList); on this is the result I get, so I guess there is some data inside of the array.

```
2011-06-14 21:51:04.690 NAF[954:207] articleList: (
"<Article: 0x8021170>",
"<Article: 0x80214a0>",
"<Article: 0x8020660>",
"<Article: 0x802ba30>",
"<Article: 0x802a520>",
"<Article: 0x80267a0>",
"<Article: 0x8025bd0>",
"<Article: 0x80141e0>",
"<Article: 0x8024390>",
"<Article: 0x8026bb0>",
"<Article: 0x8029630>",
"<Article: 0x8019390>",
"<Article: 0x8015b50>",
"<Article: 0x8014dd0>",
"<Article: 0x8012fb0>"
)
```

So to the question. How can I loop true the array and get the value of every 'title' of the XML file.
Im a hell of a cut and paste programmer, so if someone can be so helpful providing me with some code, I will appriciate it a lot.

Comment: Well, without knowing the data structure used for each article instance there's no way one can tell you how to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each article has a property called title

```
for(Article* a in articleList)
{
    NSLog(@"Title = %@",a.title);
{
```